# Very simple node.js application deployed to k8s cluster, port-forwarding is failing

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, portforwarding

I have a very simple node.js app, server is listening on port `8282`:

```
const http = require('http');
const os = require('os');
...
...
var server = http.createServer(handler);
server.listen(8282);
```

I have a `Dockerfile` for it:

```
FROM node:12
COPY app.js /app.js
ENTRYPOINT ["node","app.js"]
```

Then I built the image `myreg/my-app:1.0` successfully & deployed to my k8s cluster (AWS EKS) with the following manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: myreg/my-app:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8282
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-reg-cred

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-svc
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8282
      targetPort: 8282
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

I can see pods are running:

```
kubectl --namespace=my-ns get po
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-5477c9c798-5q4v4   1/1     Running   0          5m3s
```

Then I want to do `port-forwarding`, on my terminal:

```
$kubectl --namespace=my-ns port-forward my-app-5477c9c798-5q4v4  8282
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8282 -> 8282
Forwarding from [::1]:8282 -> 8282
```

I open another terminal window, using curl to communicate with my pod:

```
curl localhost:8282
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

On the other terminal window where port-forwarding is running:

```
Handling connection for 8282
E0411 23:12:25.254291   45793 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8282 -> 8282: error forwarding port 8282 to pod ca30fad7ea7100d684d1743573dea426caa9a333163ccbca395ed57eaa363061, uid : exit status 1: 2022/04/11 20:12:25 socat[1326] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8282, 16): Connection refused
```

Why port forwarding is failed in my implementation? What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You app is only [listen to localhost](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#netcreateconnectionport-host-connectlistener), try change `server.listen(8282)` to `server.listen(8282,"0.0.0.0")`, rebuild and update your image and restart your deployment.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why `localhost` doesn't work in this case? I mean each pod has assigned a internal IP, `kubectl` is supposed to know the IP of the pod to which to port forwarding. I wonder why `localhost` matters in this context, if kubectl knows the IP and port of the application pod.

Comment: Besides, talking from the purpose of port-forward in kubectl, it mainly for debugging application running on pod without exposing the pod. It means opening a tunnel from my localhost to cluster's pod.  Why I need to use "0.0.0.0" to make it work? It would be nice if you could elaborate.

Comment: First of all confirm the provided answer resolved the issue?

Comment: Yes, I confirm it resolved the issue. I mean I have no doubt on your answer, just would be nice to have more elaboration so that others who end up with same issue could also see the cause. Thanks.

Comment: Too lengthy for a small window, instead, try this write-up about [localhost vs 0.0.0.0](https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/). For the case of k8s, remember that `localhost` works only _inside_ the pod (port-forward is **not** a connection initiated inside the pod thus will not work for localhost). If you need your server to be reachable from outside the pod, you need to listen to all (aka 0.0.0.0).